# Windows Authentication with Not Allowing Pass-Through

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-authentication

I am trying to work out a simple, 1 .aspx page, application to use Windows authentication so the user does not have to use the browser's username/password pop-up to login at all. They just go to the URL and they are logged in.

My web config is set like this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

I have tried using:
    
and still no joy.

Using Windows Server 2003 I have anonymous access unchecked, Integrated Windows authentication check, and I am running the application as administrator so I do have permission, Enable Integrated Windows authentication under advanced tab is checked.

Any idea as to how to get this to work correctly? I know this has been asked over and over, but I have tried pretty much every suggestion I have found.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Internet Explorer, at least while debugging this authentication method
2. Add your website to trusted domains and/or local intranet lists in IE
3. Add < allow users="*"/>

And describe symptoms if 1-3 does not help.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to getting this to work is to add 'Users' to the permissions.  See this post:

[Pass-through authentication not working. IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540172/pass-through-authentication-not-working-iis-7/24430510#24430510)